# Does a lighting fixture without a ground wire need one?

Tags: electrical, lighting, grounding, led

I just bought a lighting fixture (a LED light) that has a power and a neutral line, but no ground. Is this typical for newer low power lighting, or is this lighting fixture just trash?

There are no certification markings on the box.
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0C3D4TH2J](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C3D4TH2J)

Comment: When I try to look at the picture you haven't provided, there's no way to tell. Does it have a marking from UL, ETL, or another Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory? Probably good. Is the only offical-looking mark on it CE - probably bad. Is the exposed housing metal? Probably bad. Is the exposed housing plastic or otherwise non-conductive (glass, etc.) - then it might just have a NRTL marking **and** not need a ground wire.

Comment: Is fixture plastic?  Not sure of the percentages, but would guess at least half or more light fixtures do not use ground.

Comment: It's pretty common not to have ground. I've seen fixtures with a ground wire that's connected to nothing at all inside the fixture "just so they have one". You need a ground if the fixture is metal, otherwise there's nothing to connect the ground to.

Comment: if the packaging is marked with a square inside a square mark, it's double-insulated, and thus safe to use w/o grounding. Some folks mistake the symbol for a "square-D" mark, and some folks misunderstand square-D for certification (it's a company).